# how do I drop a Table and recreate it via informatica Pre sql?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

We are Trying to Drop and recreate a table via Informatica Mapping using the Pre_Sql option. Informatica throws an Insufficient privilege error even though we have granted privileges to the Informatica user, is it possible to drop and create a table Via pre SQL or is there any other method to accomplish this issue.

Comment: You can use pre-sql, you can use pl-sql procedure and call it in presql, you can use shell script to call drop script or pl sql procedure.

Comment: Sorry for another comment, but i am curious, how are you are trying to drop the table? Which DB? May be DB is preventing drop? Have you logged in using the user used in informatica connection and try to drop it?

Comment: @KoushikRoy I am trying to Drop the table Via source qualifier pre sql and the Database is oracle Database.

Comment: Out of curiosit: Why not just truncate the table? What is the reason for drop&create?